# How come my pygame code isn't drawing this circle?

Tags: python, pygame, surface

http://pastebin.com/PLdiNg9d

First off, I'm pretty new to Python so sorry for the very sloppy code! Anyways, onto my question. I made a class cell, and in it's init function it accepts several variables that it uses to draw a circle. I then do this:

```
self.image = pygame.Surface([size, size])
self.image.fill(WHITE)
self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [posx, posy], size)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
print('Cell initialized.')
```

The problem is, it doesn't draw anything onto my screen. It doesn't output an error message, but it still prints 'Cell initialized.' so I know it's getting all the way through the **init** function.

What really confuses me is that there is a way I can get it to work. If I move

```
cell_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
a = Cell(5, GREEN, 2, 200, 200)
cell_list.add(a)
```

into my while loop, and change

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, ...)
```

to

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, ...)
```

Then it will draw my cell. Any help at all would be appreciated, because I'm thoroughly stumped.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple template to use when working with `pygame`. This demo draws a circle at the center of the screen.

```
from pygame import *
screen = display.set_mode((500,500))
# Fill screen white
screen.fill((255,255,255))

# Draw a red circle at the center
# Remove the 1 to make it a filled circle
draw.circle(screen, (255,0,0), (250,250), 250, 1)

# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    # Properly quit (pygame will crash without this)
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False

    display.flip()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [posx, posy], size)
```

use:

```
pygame.draw.circle(self.image, color, [size, size], size)
```

Explanation: on your surface (`self.image`) you draw circle on coordinates `0, 0` but because `pygamen.draw.circle` needs centre so `size, size` goes here.

If you wanted `size` to be radius use `size//2` instead of `size` in drawing circle, if you want it to be diameter use `size*2` instead of `size` in `image` initialization.

You also need to specify `rect` position, so put this somewhere in `Cell.__init__()`:

```
self.rect.x = self.posx
self.rect.y = self.posy
```

Few notes:

- use `self.variable` instead of `variable` (*e.g.:*`self.size` instead of just `size`) because you can use it anywhere in class
- put `pygame.quit()` at the end of the program (after `while` loop)